# Textbox value summation

Tags: vb.net, textbox, sum

I have two textboxes in which users enter a number, Data1.text and Data2.text. I need to do a simple check before proceeding and closing a form, i.e. the process should check if the sum of the values in Data1 and Data2 textbox is greater or lesser than the value from a label text named FinalValue.text, which gets its value from my main form.

```
    If Data1.Text + Data2.Text <> FinalValue.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("The sum of the entered values are different from the final value!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

The problem is that whatever the user enters in the two textboxes, the messagebox pops up.

For example...if the FinalValue label has a value of 58.50, and if the user enters in one textbox 50 and in the other one 8.50, the messagebox pops up. I suppose I have to format my textboxes or something like that, but not sure in which way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do  Data1.Text + Data2.Text, you are actually just concatenating the values, not doing a number Sum, you need to convert to decimal.

Something like :

```
If Decimal.Parse(Data1.Text) + Decimal.Parse(Data2.Text) <> Decimal.Parse(FinalValue.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("The sum of the entered values are different from the final value!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are integers , change your condition to match the integers sum, You are currently concatenating the strings

```
CInt(Data1.Text) + CInt(Data2.Text) <> CInt(FinalValue.Text)
```

Or for Decimals use `Decimal.Parse()` in place of `CInt()`

Comment: @Ajdin Please upvote/accept the answer if it solved your query ;)

Comment: I did, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to make it count.

Comment: @Ajdin : You can always accept an answer , if that helped you ;)